# Schema Import Fails with `type "ltree" does not exist`

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We get the following error when trying to import the schema from Postgres 9.4 into Postgres RDS 9.6:

```
ERROR:  type "ltree" does not exist
LINE 8:     path ltree,
                 ^
```

ltree is installed on the source:

```
ltree   | 1.0     | pg_catalog | data type for hierarchical tree-like structures
```

ltree is installed on the destination:

```
ltree   | 1.1     | public     | data type for hierarchical tree-like structures
```

To dump from Postgres:

```
pg_dump -h db0 -U deployer staging --schema public --schema-only > schema.dump
```

To restore to RDS:

```
psql -h staging.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U deployer -d staging < schema.dump
```

The only place in the schema dump where `ltree` occurs is this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    customer_id integer DEFAULT 0,
    ordinal integer NOT NULL,
    root_id integer,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    path ltree,
    premium boolean DEFAULT false
);
```

There is no `CREATE EXTENSION` in the dump. I've tried adding it before doing the import but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is `deployer ` a `rds_superuser`?.. otherwise you can't create an extension

Answer (score 3):

If `deployer` (the user you use to "import" dump) is `rds_superuser` you should be able to do that, if not, you will see:

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "ltree"
> HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
> ```

Eg:

```
mon=> set role stan;
SET
mon=> create extension ltree;
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "ltree"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
mon=> reset role;
RESET
mon=> create extension ltree;
CREATE EXTENSION
mon=> select session_user;
 session_user
--------------
 rdsadm
(1 row)

mon=> \du rdsadm
                           List of roles
  Role name  |          Attributes           |      Member of
-------------+-------------------------------+----------------------
 rdsadm      | Create role, Create DB       +| {rds_superuser,stan}
             | Password valid until infinity |
```